# Molecular weight of NiMnGaFe compund problem

Tags: molecular-structure, molecules, mole

I have a big problems calculating molar/molecular etc masses, because in my case I have a monocrystal, co I cannot imagine it as a molecule and my compound is made of Ni-Mn-Ga-Fe. I know the mass and the atomic and the mass percents and I need to get molecular weight.

In the atomic percents I have: 50% of Nickel, 25% of Manganese, 17,5% of Gallium and 7,5% of Iron. So the ratio (of number of atoms) is 2:1:0,7:0,3 and I can find the atomic masses of all these elements but what is going to be the molecular mass?

I am sorry for probably trivial question (I am really dumb in this area unfortunately and I was searching on the internet for answers but every time the structure of molecule was known and this is a crystal)

Comment: :/ It's an **alloy** not a compound, so there's no molecular or even molar mass.

Comment: I was thinking that but I needed to calculated the Bohr magneton f. u. from emu, so I need to search for different equation, thank you

Comment: At least now I know for sure.

Comment: Seems it's not even a single phase https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0925838818321406

Comment: This alloy has too much of iron so after Laue diffraction it looked as a polycrystal but my samples with less of iron are single phase and succesfuly oriented. Making monocrystal is just harder so there are plenty of articles about polycrystals. The magnetization measurement however were succesful for all.

Comment: https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_do_you_convert_emu_g_to_Ub_mewB_per_TM_atom I found the aswer here.